# Spring Rest - Field with @ManyToOne mapping is null

Tags: java, spring-data, h2, spring-rest

I have the below scenario:

1. 2 entities, User and Company;
2. I'm using H2database;
3. I persist a Company and everything is OK and id 1 is returned;
4. When I try to save a User to Company, my field **company_id** in database, is empty. I don't know what is happening! See my json to persist a user:

   {
       "id": null,
       "name": "My Name",
       "login": "My Login",
       "mail":"my@mail.com",
       "password":"secret",
       "federalID":"0000000",
       "company":{"id": 1}
   }

*I'll no post Controllers and other class, just will show de important to solve this. Below the classes used with your maps*.

**The User class:**

```
@Entity(name = "users")
@Table(name = "users")
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String login;
    private String mail;
    private String password;
    private String federalID;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName="company_id")
    private Company company;
}
```

**The Company class:**

```
@Entity(name="companies")
@Table(name="companies")
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String federalID;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", targetEntity=User.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
    private List<User> users;
}
```

**Rest of User Entity (*Company Controller follow the same pattern*):**

```
@RestController
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired 
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User company){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userRepository.save(company), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        userRepository.delete(id);

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be useful to see some controller code. How is the JSON being converted into the actual Java User object?

Comment: @VitorSantos I 've updated my post to you see my User Controller.

Comment: I am assuming that the JSON is being converted by Spring REST. My guess is that if you debug the controller as it is, you'll see that the company attribute in the user object is null. I would try passing the JSON as: `{ "id": null, "name": "My Name", "login": "My Login", "mail":"my@mail.com", "password":"secret", "federalID":"0000000", "company": {id: 1} }` , with the company as a JSON object.

Comment: @VitorSantos, the worst is that I already did it!  But it not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see,`Company` is a relation on your `User` class. Due to the fact that, Hibernate cannot recognize it as an initialized entity. 
 To resolve the problem, you should manually load the Company by using company_id and you should set the loaded company into the `User` class inside`UserController`.

Comment: Abdullah, thank you for the ask, the way that you explain really can be used, but I solve this problem with another way.

Comment: Was necessary do some adjusts in my code, but the base for solve the problems, was basicaly follow a post about **Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships**. You can found the post here: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

I solve my problem using the **@JsonManagedReference** annotation in my **User** class and **@JsonBackReference** annotation in my **Company** class. As well as for a bteer pattern in both classes I put a **Serializable** implements and some adjusts in Lombok annotations.

Comment: In Company class I do it: **@JsonBackReference(value = "users") private List<User> users**. In User class I do this way: **@JsonManagedReference private Company company**.

Comment: User Class: **@NotNull @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false) private Company company;**

Comment: Company Class: **@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
 @JsonBackReference(value = "users")
private List<User> users;**